# Custom concat function in C with pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I try to code my own concatenation function in C without library, but I have issue and I don't know where it comes from.
To do my function I use pointers of char.

This is my Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int longueur(char *str)
{
    int i =0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void concat(char* source, char* dest)
{
    int longStr1 = (longueur(source));
    int longStr2 = (longueur(dest));
    int i=0, j=0;
    char* temp = dest;
    free(dest);
    dest = (char*) realloc(dest, ((longStr1 + longStr2)* sizeof(char)));

    /*dest[0] = temp[0]; <------  If I do this it will generate issue, so the bellow code too*/
    while(temp[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = temp[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(source[j] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = source[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
   dest[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "World";
    char *str2 = "Hello";
    concat(str1, str2);
    printf("-------------\n%s", str2);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I read all your answer, so I changed my concat function to :

```
void concat(char* source, char* dest)
{
    int longStr1 = (longueur(source));
    int longStr2 = (longueur(dest));
    int i=0, j=0;

    dest = (char*) malloc((longStr1 + longStr2)* sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));

    while(dest[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = dest[i];
        i++;
   }
   while(source[j] != '\0')
   {
       dest[i] = source[j];
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   dest[i] = '\0';
}
```

Now I don't have issue but my code only display "Hello"

Comment: You cannot `realloc(dest` if you first `free` it: there's nothing left to re-allocate. Remove the `free(dest)` - `realloc` does this. Also, `temp` points to `free`d memory. You should also allocate 1 extra byte for the terminating `\0`.

Comment: You can try `char *str2 = strdup("Hello");`, remove the `free(dest);` and see if it works then.

Comment: As `char* temp = dest;` the ointer is copied, but not the array of char. Once `free(dest)` is called, using `temp[i]` leading to undefined behavior, such as a segementation fault.

Comment: @Ctx I try, but it doesn't work.
Thank you, @Kenney I remove the line with `free(dest)` and I write  `dest = (char*) malloc((longStr1 + longStr2)* sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));` but It always doesn't work.
Thank you, @francis why the array of char is not copied ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the good comments and solutions: `realloc` can give you a different pointer and you must return that pointer. So your function signature should be:

```
void concat(char* source, char** dest)
{
    int longStr1 = (longueur(source));
    int longStr2 = (longueur(dest));
    int i=0, j=0;
    char* temp = *dest, *temp2;
    if ((temp2 = realloc(dest, ((longStr1 + longStr2)+1))==NULL) return;
    *dest= temp2;

    while(temp[i] != '\0')
    {
        *dest[i] = temp[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(source[j] != '\0')
    {
        *dest[i] = source[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
   *dest[i] = '\0';
}
```

..and this *assumes* the function will *only* be called with a `dest` that was allocated with `malloc`. And `sizeof(char)` is always 1. (This resulting function is not optimal.)

--EDIT--

Below the correct, optimized version:

```
void concat(char* source, char** dest)
{
    int longSrc = longueur(source);
    int longDst = longueur(dest);
    char *pDst, *pSrc;

    if ((pDst = realloc(*dest, longSrc + longDst + 1))==NULL) return;

    if (pDst != *dest) *dest= pDst;

    pDst += longSrc;
    pSrc= source;

    while(pSrc)
        *pDst++ = *pSrc++;

    *pDst = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
free(dest);
```

and

```
dest = (char*) realloc(dest, ((longStr1 + longStr2)* sizeof(char)));
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as none of them use a pointer previously allocated by `malloc()` or family.

Mostly aligned with your approach, you need to make use of another pointer, allocate dynamic memory and return that pointer. Do not try to alter the pointers received as parameters as you've passed string literals.

That said, you need to have some basic concepts clear first.

1. You need not `free()` a memory unless it is allocated through `malloc()` family.
2. You need to have a `char` extra allocated to hold the terminating null.
3. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
4. If your concatenation function allocates memory, then, the caller needs to take care of `free()`-ing the memory, otherwise it will result in memory leak.

Comment: and the reason behind the downvote? Will appreciate a comment.

Comment: I still disagree with your claims that malloc should not be casted.

Comment: @Ctx it is useless to cast malloc, what is the reason to do so?

Comment: @tinky_winky Sir, let's not  start a discussion here. all the arguments, both in favor and against are presented nicely in the linked post in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

After you have freed `dest` here:

```
free(dest);
```

You cannot use this pointer in following call to `realloc`:

```
dest = (char*) realloc(dest, ((longStr1 + longStr2)* sizeof(char)));

/*dest[0] = temp[0]; <------  If I do this it will generate issue, so the bellow code too*/
```

man realloc

> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
>
> The  realloc()  function  changes  the size of the memory block
>   pointed to by ptr to size bytes. (...)

But this pointer is invalid now and you cannot use it anymore. When you call `free(dest)`, the memory `dest` points to is being freed, but the value of `dest` stays untouched, making the dest a *dangling* pointer. Accessing the memory that has already been freed produces *undefined behavior*.

NOTE:
Even if `free(dest)` is technically valid when called on pointer to memory allocated by `malloc` (it is not an error in your function to call `free(dest)` then), it is incorrect to use this on pointer to literal string as you do in your example (because `str2` points to string literal it is an error to pass this pointer to function calling `free` on it).

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is not, calling this with incorrect pointer is (and yes, this code is example of this)

Comment: I did not get you. How come `dest` is not invalid here?

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is technically OK to call free on pointer passed to function, though you must pass valid pointer. OP passes pointer to string literal which will produce UB.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your definition of `technically OK`? I think the standard is quite explicit about the pointer being allocated by dynamic allocation, isn't it?

Comment: In **isolation** code like `void func ( char * arg ) { free (arg); … }` is correct code with no UB.   It is the addition of calling it and passing it a pointer which is neither NULL nor carries a value returned by the malloc-family of function which introduces the UB.

Comment: @JohnHascall Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original use, perhaps you would find a variant like this useful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

size_t longueur ( const char * str ) {               /* correct type for string lengths */
    size_t len = 0;

    while (*str++ != '\0') ++len;
    return len;
}

char * concat ( const char * first, const char * second ) {
    const char * s1 = first  ? first  : "";          /* allow NULL input(s) to be */
    const char * s2 = second ? second : "";          /* treated as empty strings */
    size_t ls1 = longueur(s1);
    size_t ls2 = longueur(s2);
    char * result = malloc( ls1 + ls2 + 1 );         /* +1 for NUL at the end */
    char * dst = result;   

    if (dst != NULL) {
        while ((*dst = *s1++) != '\0') ++dst;        /* copy s1\0 */
        while ((*dst = *s2++) != '\0') ++dst;        /* copy s2\0 starting on s1's \0 */
    }
    return result;
}

int main ( void ) {
    const char *str1 = "Hello";
    const char *str2 = " World";
    char * greeting = concat(str1, str2);

    printf("-------------\n%s\n-------------\n", greeting);
    free(greeting);
    return 0;
}
```

In this variant, the two inputs are concatenated and the result of the concatenation is returned.  The two inputs are left untouched.

Comment: Note, by not freeing either input, the possibility of **UB** is minimized.